# Cannot convert the following file: "udhr_deu_1901.txt"(source:https://unicode.org/udhr/d/udhr_deu_1901.txt) with the command "iconv" in cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I want to convert the file

```
"udhr_deu_1901.txt" from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1.
```

Message I get from terminal is

```
     "iconv: udhr_deu_1901.txt:2:7: cannot convert".
```

I don't know what to do next. How do i convert the .txt file to ISO-8859-1?

Answer (score 0):

The file contains some characters that iconv does not succeed to translate.

We can convert skipping the not translatable character, and convert back to UTF8
to check which character we are missing:

```
$ iconv -f UTF8 -t ISO-8859-1 -c udhr_deu_1901.txt > udhr_deu_1901-8859-1.txt

$ iconv -t UTF8 -f ISO-8859-1  udhr_deu_1901-8859-1.txt > udhr_deu_1901-UTF8.txt

$ diff -uN udhr_deu_1901.txt udhr_deu_1901-UTF8.txt
--- udhr_deu_1901.txt   2017-12-14 15:35:09.000000000 +0100
+++ udhr_deu_1901-UTF8.txt      2018-11-08 18:29:18.070810900 +0100
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 Universal Declaration of Human Rights - German, Standard (1901)
-© 1996 – 2009 The Office of the High Commissioner for Human Rights
-This plain text version prepared by the “UDHR in Unicode”
+© 1996  2009 The Office of the High Commissioner for Human Rights
+This plain text version prepared by the UDHR in Unicode
 project, https://www.unicode.org/udhr.
 ---
```

So the problem are the `-`, the `“` and `”`, that I assume you can add manually

Comment: I've tried to add the characters manually but after doing so I get the same error: "iconv: udhr_deu_1901.txt:1:0: cannot convert". My thought was to remove the blank lines inside the .txt file.

Comment: I just tested it but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Make a copy of the original document.  Note the nonconvertible character location in the error message from `iconv`. The msg `iconv: udhr_deu_1901.txt:2:7: cannot convert.` indicates the problem is on line 2 at position 7. Edit the copy to globally replace the problem character with a visually similar character that will convert. You may have an m-dash or n-dash; replace with a hyphen. Change left and right double quotes to straight double quotes. Repeat until your copy converts cleanly,

Comment: My suggestion was to add the missing character after the conversion.

Comment: Okay I've tried a bit and it seems to work. Now i must count all the vowels and diphthongs in the .txt file. I've tried with "grep -c [a] udhr_deu_1901.txt" to count the vowel "a". Is this the right approach to solve this problem? (Before you ask: This is some kind of homework I have to do for my study lessons)

Comment: Why ? The `diff`shows that only those 2 lines are different in the conversion, all the rest of the document is fine

Comment: Your Method seems to work matzeri. It was my fault. I've messed around too much with the characters in the .txt file.